# Temporal, How to get RunID while being inside a workflow to terminate the current workflow?

Tags: go, temporal-workflow

I am trying to test a temporal, here is what I have tried so far

```
func (h *Temporal) Notification(ctx workflow.Context, activityType string, sleep time.Duration) (TemporalResult, error) { //Response must have error
    ao := workflow.ActivityOptions{
        StartToCloseTimeout: time.Hour * 1000,
        HeartbeatTimeout:    time.Hour * 1000,
    }
    ctx = workflow.WithActivityOptions(ctx, ao)

    if 1=1 {
        c.TerminateWorkflow(context.Background(), WORKFLOW_ID, RUN_ID )
    } else {
        workflow.Sleep(ctx, sleep)
        var result workflow.Future
        result = workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, h.SimpleActivity)
        return yourActivityResult, nil

    }
```

In side the workflow, I want to have a condition where it could terminate the current workflow. But I do not know how to get WORKFLOW_ID and RUN_ID inside a workflow

Comment: Note that using the workflow client or doing any direct service communication from the workflow code is a serious bug. Such code belongs to activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current executions run id via:

```
workflow.GetInfo(ctx).WorkflowExecution.RunID
```

Workflow id:

```
workflow.GetInfo(ctx).WorkflowExecution.ID
```

To terminate you could invoke activity (pass in this info) which can use client api to terminate the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Workflow API for terminating itself. To stop the current Workflow, return. (Either a value or an error.)

Comment: Hi @Loren what if it is a Cron Workflow where the RunID keeps changing, and I want to terminate it by an API. Not on the UI. So how to get RunID so I can store it and make another API to delete it

Comment: You can call `client.TerminateWorkflow` without a `runId` and it will terminate the current running Workflow:

https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go/blob/cee305f568f4b7cba5ec1c597d206bd0114289d7/client/client.go#L178